# Place picture under header

Tags: html, css, header

Problem in particular visibility of the picture, when you enter the site, part of the picture hide under header, some part hide even more higher(don't know why?).

Can you help me to place picture under header and make header transparent(or partly transparent), so the full picture appear on the site.

Here is my code:
HTML:`

```
<html lang="ru">
<head>...</head>

<body>

    <header>...</header>

    <div id="center">
        <form>....</form>
    </div>

    <footer> </footer>

</body>
</html>`
```

CSS:

```
html {
height: 100%;
background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

body {
margin: 0px;
font-family: sans-serif;
color: white;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

header {
height: 60px;

display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;

color: white;

width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: What about the footer? Should that also be in front of the background image?

Comment: Yes, footer should be like header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `background: rgba()` to provide a good transparent effect (This doesn't make the text transparent like `opacity` would). I provided a snippet below. Some of the other tricks I used for layout span multiple properties or they are just unintuitive, so I used comments to hopefully better explain my intentions.

I suggest using single-class selectors as much as possible (and changing HTML to allow it). It makes things easier overall. My code below reflects those changes as well.

```css
/* Background & General Styles */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Prevent padding (and borders) from adding to width/height */
}

html, body {
  margin: 0px; /* Remove browser default margins */
  padding: 0px; /* Remove browser default padding */
}

html {
  height: 100%; /* Helps min-height work properly on body */
}

body {
  position: relative; /* Assist "position: absolute" below */
  padding-top: 60px; /* Must match header height; make up for header being removed from the document flow */
  padding-bottom: 60px; /* Must match footer height; make up for footer being removed from the document flow */
  min-height: 100%; /* Force body to be at least the size of the screen */
  background: grey; /* Backup color */
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}


/* Header */
.site-header {
  position: fixed; /* Helps us position at the top; header no longer takes up space in the flow of the document */
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgb(44, 44, 44); /* Backup color */
  background: rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.5);
}


/* Main Content */
.main-content {
  padding: 15px;
}


/* Footer */
.site-footer {
  position: absolute; /* Helps us position at the bottom; footer no longer takes up space in the flow of the document */
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgb(44, 44, 44); /* Backup color */
  background: rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">header</header>
<div class="main-content">content</div>
<footer class="site-footer">footer</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpful

Comment: @WiAim No problem! Let me know if you have a question about any part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps.
Use `opacity` to make elements transparent or use `rgba color values` to show transparent background colors.

```css
html {
height: 100%;
background: url('http://placehold.it/800x800?text=example_image') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 80, 255, .5); //transparency here
}

#center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}

#center form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 246, .5); //transparency here
}

footer {
  background: rgba(88, 114, 51, .5); //transparency here
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <header>Header</header>
  <form>form</form>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show picture under header, you can try adding an opacity or a color with alpha channel.

You can try adding this to the header.

```
  Opacity: 0.7;
```

Opacity go from 1 to 0 where 0 is full transparent.
Opacity will affect everything inside header like text and images, so what you will look for is more about an alpha channel (RGBA = Red, Green, blue and alpha).
To add this you need to add something like that :

```
 Background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.5);
```

To find more about rgba colors :

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp

https://color.adobe.com/